# rpush openssl Error with password

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openssl

while using `rpush` to send push via APNS (apple-app) 
I got errors like below. It seems errors are due to problem with ruby updates, (2.4.0) However, I'm not sure why this password length problem has 
occurred and how to deal with this.

```
OpenSSL::OpenSSLError, password must be at least 4 bytes
/home/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rpush-3.0.2/lib/rpush/daemon/tcp_connection.rb:128:in `initialize'
/home/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rpush-3.0.2/lib/rpush/daemon/tcp_connection.rb:128:in `new'
/home/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rpush-3.0.2/lib/rpush/daemon/tcp_connection.rb:128:in `setup_ssl_context'
/home/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rpush-3.0.2/lib/rpush/daemon/tcp_connection.rb:39:in `connect'
/home/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rpush-3.0.2/lib/rpush/daemon/apns/feedback_receiver.rb:57:in `check_for_feedback'
```

Current version of openssl is like below

```
2.4.0 :001 > require 'openssl'
 => true
2.4.0 :002 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "2.4.0"
2.4.0 :003 > OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
 => "OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016"
2.4.0 :004 > OpenSSL::VERSION
 => "2.0.2"
2.4.0 :005 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your `openssl` gem version to `2.0.5`. The 4 bytes limit has been removed [here](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/commit/a896c3d1dfa090e92dec1abf8ac12843af6af721)

Comment: after I changed in locl `gem openssl`, `~> 2.0.5` with bundler, the deployed version does not reflect this, directing 2.0.2 @Junan Chakma

Comment: Is it only happening with ruby `2.4.0`? did you try with ruby `2.4.2`?